# awaitReactions not working when i try to role everyone who reacted

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

The error I'm getting:

```js
Error: (node:4628) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined
```

---

My code:

```js
msg.react('')
await msg.awaitReactions(() => true, {
    time: time
}).then(collected => {

    collected.users.cache.forEach((user) => {
        msg.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add('743917402714275971');
    })
});
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: Your code formatting seems off so it's hard to tell exactly what you're doing but it looks like the `users` or `members` properties is undefined. Have you tried console logging to ensure that the data you're trying to access exists?

Answer (score 0):

`message.awaitReactions()` returns a collection of `MessageReaction`. You need to loop on every `MessageReaction` collected:

```js
msg.react('')
await msg.awaitReactions(() => true, {
    time: time
}).then(collected => {

    collected.forEach((reaction) => {
 
        reaction.users.cache.forEach(user => { msg.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add('743917402714275971');
       });
    })
});
```

Comment: (node:10432) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined